# Read local file in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, file-io, ripple

I'm trying to read a local file in Phonegap to load the language strings for the application and I can't make it work :(

The code is pretty straightforward:

```
var pathToLocalFile = "/home/user/android/assets/www/js/";
var langCache = new FileReader();
langCache.onload = function(data){
  col = JSON.parse(data);
  refreshAllStrings();
};
langCache.onerror = function(err){
  debug.error(err);
};
langCache.readAsText(pathToLocalFile+currentLang+'.json');
```

This code doesn't work on the Ripple emulator and I replaced it with

```
var pathToLocalFile = "file:///android_asset/www/js/";
```

in case of android, with the same result:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Console> has no method 'warning' cordova-2.4.0.js:2616
initRead cordova-2.4.0.js:2616
FileReader.readAsText cordova-2.4.0.js:2660    
loadLanguage
```

In the Ripple emulator, I started Chrome with `google-chrome -–allow-file-access-from-files` and the Android config and manifest has all the permissions for and the plugins set.

Of course I'm missing something, but any idea what this could be?

Regards.

Comment: Sorry, to better answer you I just need to clarify one thing. Are you trying to read a JS file that you are including in the www directory of your Android app?

Comment: yep, exactly, that's what i want, a way to dynamically load the file that is in the app package (i supposed that FileRead would work, i'm open to any other suggestion)

Comment: Yeah, the FileReader does not have access to the files packaged with the application. Reading those files is best done via AJAX as per @codemonkey answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the file is under the www folder of your app you don't need to add '/home/..' or 'file:///'. You should just be able to load the contents using an "AJAX" fetch even though it is bundled in the app.

```
$.get('js/filename.ext');
```

Comment: this worked on android emulator but not in ripple (would be great if i can get it working on ripple, is terribly slow to make a change, compile and run the emulator on android :( )

Comment: fixed it, changing the cross domain policy of ripple works :D

Comment: How do I write to this local file?

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing is actually a result of cordova-2.4.0.js calling a non-existent "warning" method.  It should be console.warn.  It is attempting to warn you that using a string for the readAsText method is now deprecated, and that you should use a File reference instead.

What should be happening is a console.warn of "Using a string argument with FileReader.readAs functions is deprecated."